# IMPLODE data by checkbox

Tags: php, explode, implode

i have this Interface where the user can add a flower [image: interface]

The user need to add a flower to the database and he can make them in different occasions a categories (the check boxes). Now to implode the data i made this code:

```
 $occasions = implode( ';' , $_POST['reg_occassions'] );
                 $categories= implode( ';' , $_POST['reg_categories'] );

            $query = 
            "INSERT INTO tbl_flower (flower_type, website_description,florist_description,name,image,enabled,florist_choice,categories,occasions)
             VALUES ('$flowertype', '$websitedescription', '$floristdescription','$name', '$upfile', '$enabled','$floristchoice', '$categories','$occasions')";
```

In the database they save as follows :

```
id      flower name      occasions                   categories

1        Rose            Birthday;Valentines        Bouqet;flower arrangment
```

Now the user can edit a flower too.This is the interface
[image]

PROBLEM!:
i dont have an idea how can i make the checkboxes again and show him which one he checked and he can change the data. I need to know how can i show the checkboxes and which one he checked will be checked too .

Thank and I really appreaciate  if someone can help me.

**EDIT Answer:** This is the interface of the checkboxes.
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do something like:

```
$results = "Bouqet,flower arrangment"; //results from your database
$resultsArray = explode(",", $results); //split the comma
$checkValue = array("Bouqet", "flower arrangment", "other"); //your checkbox values
$html = "";
foreach($checkValue as $val)
{
    if(in_array($val,$resultsArray ))
        $html .= '<input type="checkbox" name="flower" value="'.$val.'" checked>'.$val.'<br>';
    else
        $html .= '<input type="checkbox" name="flower" value="'.$val.'">'.$val.'<br>';
}
echo $html;
```

[<kbd>**Check Demo Here**</kbd>](http://phpfiddle.org/lite?code=%3C?php%5Cn%20$results%20=%20%22Bouqet,flower%20arrangment%22;%5Cn%20$resultsArray%20=%20explode(%22,%22,%20$results);%5Cn%20$checkValue%20=%20array(%22Bouqet%22,%20%22flower%20arrangment%22,%20%22other%22);%5Cn%20$html%20=%20%22%22;%5Cn%20foreach($checkValue%20as%20$val)%5Cn%20%7B%5Cn%5Ct%20if(in_array($val,$resultsArray%20))%5Cn%5Ct%20$html%20.=%20'%3Cinput%20type=%22checkbox%22%20name=%22flower%22%20value=%22'.$val.'%22%20checked%3E'.$val.'%3Cbr%3E';%5Cn%5Ct%20else%5Cn%5Ct%5Ct%20$html%20.=%20'%3Cinput%20type=%22checkbox%22%20name=%22flower%22%20value=%22'.$val.'%22%3E'.$val.'%3Cbr%3E';%5Cn%20%7D%5Cn%5Cn%20echo%20$html;%5Cn%5Cn?%3E%5Cn)

**EDIT:** I am making this edit because of your comments, you need to do something like:(not tested)

```
<div class="table-responsive col-md-4"> 
    <table> 
        <thead>Occasions</thead> 

        /**flower occassions **/
        $flowerCategoriesQry "SELECT categories FROM tbl_flower where id = 1"; //you need to change the where clause to variable
        $flowerResults = mysqli_query($conn, $flowerCategoriesQry) 
        $categoriesRow =  $flowerResults->fetch_assoc();
        $resultsArray = explode(",", $categoriesRow['categories']); 


        /**All Occassions **/
        $query544="SELECT name FROM tbl_occasions";
        $results544 = mysqli_query($conn, $query544);


        while ($row = $results544->fetch_assoc()) { ?> 
            <div class="col-md-12"> 
                <label class="checkbox" for="checkboxes"> 
                <?php 
                 if(in_array($row['name'],$resultsArray ))
                 {
                ?>
                     <input type="checkbox" name="flower" value="<?php echo $row['name'];?>" checked> <?php echo $row['name'];?> >
               <?php }
                 else{
               ?>
                     <input type="checkbox" name="flower" value="<?php echo $row['name'];?>" ><?php echo $row['name'];?> >
           <?php echo} $row['name']?> </label>  
            </div> <?php }?> 
    </table>
```

Comment: the problem is that the user can add more occasions and categories

Comment: Can i make a query to select all occasiosn and put them in an array ?

Comment: I am not sure if I understand what you are saying, can you please elaborate

Comment: @SigmondGatt of course, the array you see on my answer is just an example

Comment: Hey broo, sry for distrubing you , can you make me a fiddle with a  query instead of an array, SORRY FOR BEING EGOIST. (query SELECT * FROM tbl_occasions)

Comment: Only the checkvalue i dont know how to do.

Comment: I cant do the query on the fiddle because the fiddle doesn't have a database.....how were your check-boxes at first? where were you getting those values? from the query? show me that part and I will change my answer to accomodate that

Comment: $query544="SELECT name FROM tbl_occasions";
 $results544 = mysqli_query($conn, $query544)
  or die("Error in query: ". mysqli_error($conn));
 $resultsArray = explode(",", $results544);                
 $checkValue = array($resultsArray);
  $html = "";
 foreach($checkValue as $val)
 { if(in_array($val,$resultsArray ))
 $html .= '<input type="checkbox" name="flower" value="'.$val.'" checked>'.$val.'<br>';
else{
 $html .= '<input type="checkbox" name="flower" value="'.$val.'">'.$val.'<br>';
 } echo $html;
error:explode() expects parameter 2 to be string, object given in line ....

Comment: <div class="table-responsive col-md-4">
             <table>
                 <thead>Occasions</thead>
             <?php
              $query23 = "SELECT * from tbl_occasions";
   $result23 = mysqli_query($conn, $query23)
  or die("Error in query: ". mysqli_error($conn));        
  while ($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result23))
   {
  ?>
 <div class="col-md-12">
             <label class="checkbox" for="checkboxes"> 
 <input type="checkbox" name="reg_occassions[]"  value="<?php echo $row['name'];?>"><?php echo $row['name']?> 
</label></div>
 <?php }?></table>

Comment: the second one is where i get the values of the cehcbox the first one is the code i tried that you gave me soryy :P

Comment: thank you i will try , sorry for wasting your time i really appreciate

Comment: I tried it and it is not working fine can you add me skype i send a friend request so i cant finish this thing please. we are nearly there

Comment: show me the code you tried, copy and paste the whole thing into a fiddle https://jsfiddle.net/ , save it and send me the link

Comment: [Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/ggz5xgu6/)  it working all fine i repair everything the only problem is the design because if the first checkbox is selected it becomes like thead than i try with divs.. i copy paste the link of the fiddle dont know if it works or no

Comment: i dont understand what you're saying, you mean it looks like this:  [CLICK ME](https://jsfiddle.net/Luthando/ggz5xgu6/1/) ???

Comment: i will edit the question and post an image of the interface

Comment: it is doing that because of the `<label>` tag that is not closed, try copy and paste this [UPDATED LINK](https://jsfiddle.net/Luthando/ggz5xgu6/4/) - please also copy and paste the css you see on the right corner, it will also help

Comment: i edit the question again and this what happens when i copy and paste your code, right now i am editing photos so if you want leave it and i try my self .. thanks for your time

Comment: I wish i could jump into your browser and `right click > then  inspect`, am sure its a small html/css issue, try to play around with it, try to also remove `style="display:block;"` on the input

Comment: i try something wait

Comment: yeahh check the answer ! :D.. thannk you !!

Comment: Flash i know that i am an egoist person. But you know how for example :

The user will choose Valentines from a dropdown lost and i show all the flowers that valentine's checkbox is checked in a table. If you don't have time no problem.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/121230/discussion-between-the-flash-and-sigmond-gatt).

Answer (score 1):

This is the answer. Thanks to the Flash!

```
session_start();
$conn = ConnectToSql();
?>
<div class="table-responsive col-md-6" style="border:1px solid blue"> 


    <div class="col-md-6">Categories</div> 
    <div class="col-md-6">Occasions</div>
 <hr>

    <div class="col-md-6">
<?php
    /**flower occassions **/
    $flowerCategoriesQry= "SELECT categories FROM tbl_flower where id ='$_SESSION[flower]'"; 
    $flowerResults = mysqli_query($conn, $flowerCategoriesQry) ;
    $categoriesRow =  $flowerResults->fetch_assoc();


    $resultsArray = explode(";", $categoriesRow['categories']); 


    /**All Occassions **/
    $query544="SELECT name FROM tbl_categories";
    $results544 = mysqli_query($conn, $query544);


    while ($row = $results544->fetch_assoc()) { ?> 

            <label class="checkbox" for="checkboxes"> 
            <?php 
             if(in_array($row['name'],$resultsArray ))
             {
            ?>
                 <input  type="checkbox" name="edit_categories[]" value="<?php echo $row['name'];?>" checked> <?php echo $row['name'];?> 
           <?php 
             }
             else{
           ?>
                 <input  type="checkbox" name="edit_categories[]" value="<?php echo $row['name'];?>" ><?php echo $row['name']; } ?>
        </label>  

    <?php 
         }
    ?> 
    </div>
```

[click here for code](https://jsfiddle.net/ya9bxxjh/)